# Remove stop words from query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-6

I am working on Elastic Search 6.4.2. I want to apply stopwords filter to my index  inorder to restrict the stopwords queries. I added [my_stopwords.txt](https://a5a5687e-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/kevinbouge/stopwords-lists/stopwords_en.txt?attachauth=ANoY7cpcVniMrS-BMGxVILVh_LVXnyjXi_TYQ2BdByy4YZLFtEl6486xeMBPuvX94Y_uQ0jT5VVfxTnqsy7J_YdRzBZRAMn3l4o5r36TEp4tVoTpmDr0xw2lY6YfyBWMajpvOCj_PuXiyGAnKtjweAtS5-sOUJZWycXauUgQpr6-Lp_kyNSsV5u3wPU7VmBFKehmqP-YKgyqXupeaaXwXkUAGBhlV5OmYJ8VvUwXy-tiZ9QCPoGwqDA%3D&attredirects=0&d=1) in the config. I added stopword analyzers but when I check in Kibana the stopwords still searching theindex. How can I restrict this.

```
PUT /some-index
{  
   "settings":{  
      "analysis":{  
         "analyzer":{  
            "blogs_analyzer":{  
               "type":"standard",
               "stopwords_path":"stopwords/my_stopwords.txt"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{  
      "doc":{  
         "_source":{  
            "enabled":true
         },
         "properties":{  
            "content":{  
               "type":"text",
               "index":"true",
               "store":true,
               "analyzer":"blogs_analyzer",
               "search_analyzer":"blogs_analyzer"
            },
            "host":{  
               "type":"keyword"
            },
            "title":{  
               "type":"text",
               "index":"true",
               "store":true,
               "analyzer":"blogs_analyzer",
               "search_analyzer":"blogs_analyzer"
            },
            "url":{  
               "type":"keyword"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your query, I created a sample index with the above mapping and it looks to be working as expected. For sake of simplicity and to evalulate `stop_words`, I only used used `title` in the mapping, however it seems to be working as expected. Also it would be great if you can let me know the complete path for the `my_stopwords.txt`.

Comment: It was a blunder mistake from my side it didn't added the stopwords in the stopwords.txt. The above mappings worked and I searched `GET /someindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "to",
      "fields": ["title^4", "content"]
    }
  }
}`